# 'int' object has no attribute 'extend' - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to evaluate power series using python. series => e^x = 1+ x+ x^2/2! + x^3/3!...x^n/n!
I am getting this error ''int' object has no attribute 'extend'.

My code:

```
import math
print('give x')

x = float(input())

n =100
k = 0
list = (1)

while 0<x<1:
      list.extend([math.pow(x,K+1))])
      k = k+1
      if x==n:
            break

print(sum(list))
```

Please help!

Comment: 1) Don't shadow names of built-in types. 2) `(1)` is not a list, it's an integer, which doesn't have the `extend` method. 3) List literals are formed with square brackets `[1]`.

Comment: Lists use square brackets `[]`. Probably you are looking for the `list.append` method: https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code.

Firstly, you are attempting to create a list with `(1)` - that just creates the integer object `1`, the parentheses have no effect here. To create a list containing `1` you need `[1]`. And you shouldn't use the names of Python built-ins (like `list`) as variable names - not only is it confusing to other people who may read your code it makes the built-in inaccessible, which can lead to mysterious bugs.

`K` is not the same as `k`.

Your `while 0<x<1:` test does't make much sense; FWIW, the Taylor series for e<sup>x</sup> converges for all values of x.
Your `if x==n:` test should be `if k==n:`, although it'd be better to use a `for` loop with `range` (or maybe `xrange` in Python 2).

You don't need to save the terms in a list - just add them as you go.

You don't need `math.pow` - `x**k` calculates the same thing as `math.pow(x, k)`, but even that's unnecessary here: you should just keep track of the previous term and multiply it by `x` on each loop.

You forgot the `/n!`. Once again, you don't really need to compute the factorial (or call the `math.factorial` function) since you can just divide the previous term by `k`.

Hopefully, that's given you enough clues to fix your code. I won't provide working code at this stage, since I suspect this is a homework problem. Note that the `math` module has an `exp` function which you can use to test the accuracy of your power series calculations.

Answer (score 0):

A `list` literal is created with square brackets, `[]`. You can use parentheses, `()`, for grouping or for creating a `tuple`. In the case of `list = (1)`, they are being used for grouping, so this is the same as `list = 1`. (A `tuple` with one element is created with `mytuple = (1,)` or just `mytuple = 1,`.)

At this point, I'll mention that naming one of your variables `list` masks the built-in function `list`, so after you do that you can't access that function anymore without some effort. It's best to name your object something else, like `lst`.

A `list`'s `extend()` method adds all the elements from the passed `list` onto the object you're accessing, so if `mylist` was `[1, 2, 3]`, `mylist.extend([4, 5])` would result in `mylist` becoming `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. However, you only have one object to add, so it makes more sense to use `append()`, which adds the passed object to the given `list`.

```
x = float(input('Give x: ')) # the input function can be passed a prompt string
n = 100
k = 0
lst = [1] # changed name, created a list

while 0<x<1:
      list.append(x**(k+1)) # you can just use the ** operator if you want
                            # also, k isn't K
      k = k+1
      if x==n: # x is never changed, so your loop either never runs
               # or goes forever
            break

print(sum(lst))
```

Note the `while` loop that will either never be entered or never finish. You'll have to take another look at your program's logic.